# How to fit the data obtained from 2d binning?

Tags: python, matplotlib, best-fit-curve

I have 2 data sets, I see there is a correlation. But the line of best fit is being strongly influenced a few denser regions in the scatter plot. So I decided to use matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d for 2d binning. Now I am curious to see if there is an improvement in identifying the correlation i.e. line of best fit best represents the actual correlation without the effect of bin count.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import copy

num_samples = 400

# The desired mean values of the sample.
mu = np.array([5.0, 0.0, 10.0])

# The desired covariance matrix.
r = np.array([
        [  3.40, -2.75, -2.00],
        [ -2.75,  5.50,  1.50],
        [ -2.00,  1.50,  1.25]
    ])

# Generate the random samples.
rng = np.random.default_rng()
y = rng.multivariate_normal(mu, r, size=num_samples)

plt.subplot(111)
plt.plot(y[:,1], y[:,2], 'b.', alpha=0.25)
plt.plot(mu[1], mu[2], 'ro', ms=3.5)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()


##plotting 2d histogram, 2dbinning

plt.hist2d(y[:,1], y[:,2], bins=30, cmap='rainbow')#, cmin=5, cmax=33)
cb=plt.colorbar()
cb.set_label('counts in bin')
plt.show()

##showing the pearson correlation values for the fit
pccSi_raw = stats.pearsonr(y[:,1], y[:,2])
# pccSi_afterbinning = stats.pearsonr(xedges, yedges)
print("Python's Pearson Correlation Coefficient for the raw data: " + str(pccSi_raw))
# print("Python's Pearson Correlation Coefficient for the binned data: " + str(pccSi_afterbinning))
```

pccSi_afterbinning = stats.pearsonr(xedges, yedges)
print("Python's Pearson Correlation Coefficient for the binned data: " + str(pccSi_afterbinning))

as shown above lines (not correct approach anyway), somehow I want to know how to get the two 1d arrays after binning to do the fitting.
Thank you for your inputs.